# Sending email via Gmail

Tags: perl, email, gmail, ssl

I have email sending code which doesn't work without any error messages (by "doesn't work" i mean all seams OK but i have **no message in my mail box**):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Send;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

report_update();

sub report_update {

    my $mailer = Email::Send->new(
        {
            mailer      => 'SMTP::TLS',
            mailer_args => [
                Host     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                Port     => 587,
                User     => $CONFIG{EMAIL_USER},
                Password => $CONFIG{EMAIL_PASS},
                Hello    => 'localhost',
            ]
        }
    );

    my $email = Email::Simple->create(
        header => [
            From    => $CONFIG{EMAIL_USER},
            To      => $CONFIG{TARGET_EMAIL},
            Subject => 'Updated info finded!',
        ],
        body => 'Updated info finded!',
    );

    eval { $mailer->send($email) };
    die "Error sending email: $@" if $@;

    print "Finished!\n";
}
```

Could you give me a hint what's wrong with it?

Comment: Unrelated but past tense from "find" is "found" not "finded".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Send-Gmail) which might make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me this module! Now i use it in my code but the question is still in my head: Why this code don't work?